# linq compiled query, class field

Tags: linq, compiled-query

How can I insted of    **public var compiledQuery** write **Func < MYEntities,string, ???>**

```
    public var compiledQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((AddresEntities ctx, string name) =>
    from x in ctx.User
    where x.Name.Contains(name)
    select new { x.Name, x.Phone});
```

When I try it like this i get error:  **Only parametar less constructor are suported**

```
 public static   Func<AddresEntities, string, IQueryable<MYClass>> compiledQuery =
           CompiledQuery.Compile((AddresEntities ctx, string name) =>
                                 (from x in ctx.Users
                                  where x.Name.Contains(name)
                                   select new MYkontakt( x.Name, x.Phone)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try. Hope this will work

```
IEnumerable<yourType> compiledQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((AddresEntities ctx, string name) =>
from x in ctx.User
where x.Name.Contains(name)
select new yourType { x.Name, x.Phone});
```

Comment: Cannot initialize type 'Database.User_Services.MyUser' with a collection initializer 
because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: if it is not an IEnumerable type. it think you can return only anonymous type :(

Comment: So if I implement IEnumerable in my class MyUser this will be slowed.

Comment: So it is impossibile to have compiledQuery  as a Class field which have ***select new** statement, if there is some workaround this if someone knows please write it here.